# Capture only a part of the screen with MediaProjection

Tags: android, screen-capture, android-mediaprojection

I need to record only specific view and child views inside that view but to exclude other views on the Activity/Screen. Currently I'm working on one project and a thought that I can solve the problem with MediaProjection API. As I said, I need to record a specific view inside the activity.
I found an answer on similar thread: [Capturing a part of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539245/is-it-possible-to-capture-only-a-part-of-the-screen-or-even-of-a-particular-vie)
But it said that it is not possible with MediaProjection API.

Does the Google provide other solution or does someone has a similar issue or maybe even some solution to the problem?

Thanks

Comment: "Does the Google provide other solution" -- no, sorry.

Comment: Hi slena17, have you found any solution? If yes, then please share it.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not found any solution yet because as far as I now, Google does not provide screen capturing of desired view.

Comment: Have you tried SurfaceView ? @slena17

Comment: No, I did not try with SurfaceView but this maybe could be a way to go based on this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817742/how-can-i-capture-a-video-recording-on-android)